# how to make an infinite loop on array

Tags: php, arrays

i need to get an item out of an array every 5 time i loop on a for clause

my array

```
$myArray = array( 1 => 'element 1',  2 => 'element 2',  3 => 'element 3' );
```

my for loop

```
for ($i=1; $i<=50; $i++) {

  echo "echo this each time ";

  if ($i%5 === 0) $myitem = next($myArray);
  echo "echo my array item every 5 times " .$myitem; 
  // but starting again from first if i reach the end of array

}
```

i need to get first item in array if i reach the end

Comment: you need circular loop... why are you going with such a complex method.? what exactly you want.? you want to echo each element 5 times? or you want to go to 1st element when last element is reached.?

Comment: i display some images in the first FOR loop every 5 images i need to display 1 banner, but banner are a lot less than images so after i reach last banner i need to restart from first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have no idea why u need this but something like this should work:

```
$fancyvarname = 0;

for ($i=1; $i<=50; $i++) {

   echo "echo this each time ";

   if ($i%5 == 0){
      $myitem = $myArray[$fancyvarname % count($myArray)];
      $fancyvarname++;
      echo "echo my array item every 5 times " .$myitem; 
   }

}
```

EDIT: Do you noticed the *===* instead of *==* ?

Comment: Yes, i thinks it will work. As soon as i tested i came back, i add a comment on my first post explaining what i need it for.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
if ($i % sizeof($myArray) === 0 ) reset($myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for $i=0; $i<50; $i++) {
    if ($i%5===0) echo "...5 times ".$myArray[$i%count($myArray)];
}
```

of course you can take the count() outside of the loop to save a bit of cpu time